# Setting accent color in a circle behind icon image in android with pushwoosh/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

My app is using ionic (cordova). I want to ["Use setColor() to set an accent color in a circle behind your icon image"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications) at the lockscreen and notifications tray.

Like the sms sent from Stian Sandø has a blue background in the screenshot. Is this possible to do without being native?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Look for a [plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html?q=). Or a [preference setting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File).

Comment: Can't find any. I have tried to google a lot without any luck.

Comment: After reading the documentation. I found this nice link at the top of the page -- [Ask Community](https://community.pushwoosh.com/) To me, this appears to be a better place to ask the question, you are asking. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think this also concerns more than just pushwoosh. Like cordova (plugin?) may be relevant here, I am not sure.

Comment: If the answer involves cordova or phonegap, then the community at pushwoosh will know. We are not familiar with the specifics of pushwoosh, but I suspect they are familiar with cordova/phonegap.